# convert AVAudioRecorder to NSString or bytes

Tags: ios, json, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to send AVAudioRecorder in Json
,
i would like to convert it to NSString or Byte..
any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never tried but maybe this ?

```
// Get the recording
AVAudioRecorder *recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:filePath settings:recordSetting error:&error];
....
// Convert to NSData
NSData *theData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
// Convert to NSString
NSString* dataAsString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[theData bytes]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have completed a recording with AVAudioRecorder, you can retrieve the recorded file using your AVAudioRecorder's `url` property. Then you can initialize an NSData with the url:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url];
```

To send it as JSON, you need to base64 the data. I recommend this project which has a category for doing this: https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64

You'll need to `#import "NSData+Base64.h"` into your source and then you can get the base64 string from your NSData by calling `base64EncodedString` on it.